# Access Denied when connecting remotely to SQL Integration Services using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have the following PowerShell script to connect to a remote Sql Server Integration Service:

```
param (
    [string]$Server = "GFDBS0002",
    [string]$Instance = "DEFAULT",
    [string]$Folder = "<SSIS folder>",
    [string]$Project
)

Import-Module sqlps -DisableNameChecking

$p = Get-Item SQLSERVER:\SSIS\$Server\$Instance\Catalogs\SSISDB\Folders\$Folder\Projects\$Project
```

Executing the script fails with:

> "WARNING: Could not obtain SQL Server Service information. An attempt
>   to connect to WMI on 'GFDBS0002' failed with the following error:
>   Access Denied. (Undtagelse fra HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"

[I can successfully connect to the server with Windows Management Instrumentation Tester with my AD-user](https://4sysops.com/archives/wbemtest-part-1-testing-wmi-connectivity/):

[image]

Any suggestions on what I could do to connect ?

## Solution

Based on the answer by @ArcSet, the following solution worked:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "PlainTextPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("username", $secpasswd)

$p = Get-Item SQLSERVER:\SSIS\$Server\$Instance\Catalogs\SSISDB\Folders\$Folder\Projects\$Project -Credential $mycreds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WMI connection doesn't pass your identity and will need you to sign in with your credentials.

```
Get-Item -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Comment: Added that on the line before Import-Module. Getting this error: The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. Perform the operation again without specifying credentials.

Comment: $p = Get-Item 
SQLSERVER:\SSIS\$Server\$Instance\Catalogs\SSISDB\Folders\$Folder\Projects\$Project -Credential (Get-Credential)

Thats what your running?